# How to fetch last value in a dynamic array

Tags: vba

I am trying to fetch the last value of a dynamic array in VBA. The array is imported from a database and a new line is added for every day. It looks like this:

Variable(1865)
     Variable(1865,0) 05/25/2020
     Variable(1865,1) 26595
I am doing a division that will use the Variable(i,1) value. How can I do this ?

Comment: Have a look to `UBound`

Comment: Also besides [Ubound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function) , you may want to test for non-null or non-default initialized values, have a look at the Remarks on the [Redim Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement)